# Unit Testing for the following :

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

Tring to set up a unit testing for the following code, but I keep getting this:  Comparing two different types of values. Expected string but received undefined. as an error

```
 Test :


     import {prepadSigned} from './utils';

  describe('prepadSigned', () => {test('should prepend `00` to the input      <', () => {
  const str = '-10';
  const actual = prepadSigned(str);
  const expected = '00-10';
    expect(actual).toEqual(expected);
    })
```

Code:

```
function prepadSigned(hexStr) {
  const msb = hexStr[0];
  if (msb < '0' || msb > '7') {
    return `00${hexStr}`;
  }
  return hexStr;
}
```

I expect a unit test to pass with some input/output. 
I keep getting the following :

```
expect(received).toEqual(expected)

Expected value to equal:
  "00-10"
Received:
  undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you deliberately left out `export` when you wrote,

changing

```
function prepadSigned(hexStr) {
...
}
```

to

```
export function prepadSigned(hexStr) {
...
}
```

may fix the problem.

Comment: Test fails  prepadSigned › should output the same input

    expect(received).toEqual(expected)

    Expected value to equal:
      "005"
    Received:
      "5"

Comment: I guess you tried with `const str = '5'` and `const expected = '005'` there? Isn't that result expected given your implementation?

Comment: Nevermind - It worked. I Based on the main code: (msb < '0' || msb > '7') , IF a number is between 0 - 7, function will fail . Right ?I am new to unit testing

Comment: According to your test case, success/failure depends on values set to `const str` and `const expected`. It's good practice to test both success and failure scenarios.